# How to replace zeros in spotfire without creating new column

Tags: spotfire

I have table as below:

```
Name       Trans
abc          0.00
zzz          1.22
xyz          0.00
lll          22.31
lal          0.10
ppp          0.00
```

How can I replace the values 0.00 in the trans column with the value 0.01 without creating new column.

Comment: replace with 0.01

Answer (score 2):

You can use insert transformation => calculate and replace column.
You basically replace the original column with a new version where you replaced the values 0.00 with 0.01.

formula you can use: `If([Trans] = 0.00, 0.01, [Trans])`

Comment: thanks @phiver ,in this case we need to create a new column , but how to replace within the same column without creating a new column

Comment: the transformation is in the load / refresh pipeline. So you actually do not see the replacement action as a user. Everything else, like coding in r, will still replace the column. If this is a source issue, I would replace the column with a new column, just to be able to trace the fact you transformed incorrect input.

Comment: You can also try just to replace this inside Visualization, yet you won't be able to do that everywhere. phiver's way is the best one here.